# Email domain if/else check html

Tags: javascript, html

Currently I am using a pattern element to verify whether an email contains a specified domain:

```
<input type="email" id="ms_email" name="ms_email" required placeholder="Corporate Email address" **pattern="\w+@barclays\"** oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter your corporate email')" style="float:left; margin-left: 20px; clear:right;">
```

But now I want it to validate if email contains 'x' or 'y'.

What would be the best way? As pattern only seems valid for one domain not more than 1.

Thanks

Comment: Just to confirm , you're only accepting email ids from a single domain right?

Comment: I can imagine using an `input` element to fill in the part before the `@`, combined with a `select` element that holds the options. Or fixed in case of only one option. Easier to validate imho.

Comment: @SatejS from multiple domains e.g. if it was only from supermarkets like tesco or sainsbury. However the email can be @ finance.sainsburys.com or @ tesco.com. So email after the @ must contain 'sainsbury' or 'tesco' to be accepted as valid